# Django Form with Foreign Key Related Data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am having some issues with having my form have the user select a value rather than typing it into a text box. I am trying to create a tool checkout transaction, which requires the ToolID, Quantity of the tool checked out, and the PartyID. I would like to let the user be able to see a list of the users First and Last Names rather than select the PartyID. 
The First and Last Names are required but when I make a form containing those fields it gives me a text box for input. I believe I would rather have the user select the desired user from a drop down option. Any help would be appreciated.

Models:

```
class Party(models.Model):
PartyID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='PartyID')
FirstName=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
LastName=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
PhoneNumber=models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False)
Organization=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Deleted=models.BooleanField(default=0)

objects=models.Manager()

class Meta:
    managed=True
    db_table='Party'

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.PartyID)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("ToolSearch:borrowerUpdate", kwargs={"pk": self.PartyID})

class ToolTransaction(models.Model):
CheckOutID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
ToolID=models.ForeignKey(Tool, db_column='ToolID', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
PartyID=models.ForeignKey(Party, db_column='PartyID', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
Quantity=models.IntegerField(null=False)
CheckOutDate=models.DateField(null=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)
CheckInDate=models.DateField(null=True)
Deleted=models.BooleanField(default=0)
objects=ActiveTransactionManager()
#objects=models.Manager()

class Meta: 
    managed=True
    db_table='ToolTransaction'
    ordering=('CheckOutID',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.CheckOutID)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("ToolSearch:toolCheckin", kwargs={"pk": self.CheckOutID})

class Tool(models.Model):
ToolID=models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key = True, unique=True, db_column='ToolID')
Quantity=models.IntegerField(null=False)
Location=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
CategoryID=models.IntegerField(null=True)
Deleted=models.BooleanField(default=0)

objects=models.Manager()

class Meta:
        managed=True
        db_table='Tool'

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.ToolID

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("ToolSearch:toolSearchResults", kwargs={"pk": self.ToolID})
```

Forms:

```
class BorrowerSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Party
    fields = [
        "FirstName",
        "LastName",
        "PhoneNumber"
    ]

class ToolCheckoutCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ToolTransaction
    fields = [
        "ToolID",
        "Quantity",
        "PartyID",
    ]
```

View:

```
def tool_checkout(request):
    queryset = Party.objects.all()
    form = ToolCheckoutCreateForm(request.POST or None)
    form2 = BorrowerSelectForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "Tool Checked Out succesfully")
    context={
        "form": form,
        "form2": form2
    }
    return render(request, "toolcheckout.html", context)
```

I would also be fine with using one form if I can have the ToolCheckOutCreateForm also reference objects from the Party Model as opposed to having two forms be displayed at once. Just not sure about the best method to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my approach and ended up solving this problem. I was incorrect in how I was using my models. I was making one model per database table. However, what I needed to do was make one model per task that is to be performed. For instance, CheckIn and CheckOut both use the ToolTransaction model. By making a CheckIn Model (identical to ToolTransaction model above), and a CheckOut Model I was able to add reverse lookups to the correct url/view to complete the action. Also I combined an html built form which I placed my data inside and made un-editable from data I retrieved from a queryset in the view. Then I continued to use the form ToolCheckoutCreateForm. My html form held my borrower information.